# Error while performing acr run build: MONGODB_URI environment variable in .env.local

Tags: next.js, github-actions, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I am running github actions for Building and deploying a Next.js app in AKS. While in the Build and push image to ACR step I am getting an error that MONGODB_URL should be defined in .env.local while creating an optimized build.

Error:

```
   Creating an optimized production build ...

 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types ...
   Collecting page data ...
Error: Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local
```

I have already put env variables in the Manifest.yaml file

Workflow file

```
name: Build and deploy an app to AKS

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY: "abc"
  CONTAINER_NAME: "abc"
  RESOURCE_GROUP: "abc"
  CLUSTER_NAME: "abc"
  DEPLOYMENT_MANIFEST_PATH: "./manifest.yaml"

jobs:
  buildImage:
    permissions:
      contents: read
      id-token: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checks out the repository this file is in
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Logs in with your Azure credentials
      - name: Azure login
        uses: azure/login@v1.4.6
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

      # Builds and pushes an image up to your Azure Container Registry
      - name: Build and push image to ACR
        run: |
          az acr build --image ${{ env.AZURE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY }}.azurecr.io/${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}:${{ github.sha }} --registry ${{ env.AZURE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY }} -g ${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }} .
  deploy:
    permissions:
      actions: read
      contents: read
      id-token: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [buildImage]
    steps:
      # Checks out the repository this file is in
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Logs in with your Azure credentials
      - name: Azure login
        uses: azure/login@v1.4.6
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

      # Use kubelogin to configure your kubeconfig for Azure auth
      - name: Set up kubelogin for non-interactive login
        uses: azure/use-kubelogin@v1
        with:
          kubelogin-version: 'v0.0.25'

      # Retrieves your Azure Kubernetes Service cluster's kubeconfig file
      - name: Get K8s context
        uses: azure/aks-set-context@v3
        with:
          resource-group: ${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }}
          cluster-name: ${{ env.CLUSTER_NAME }}
          admin: 'false'
          use-kubelogin: 'true'

      # Deploys application based on given manifest file
      - name: Deploys application
        uses: Azure/k8s-deploy@v4
        with:
          action: deploy
          manifests: ${{ env.DEPLOYMENT_MANIFEST_PATH }}
          images: |
            ${{ env.AZURE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY }}.azurecr.io/${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}:${{ github.sha }}
```

Manifest.yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: app.azurecr.io/app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: MONGODB_URI
          value: "mongodb+srv://webapp:abc"
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: app
```

Comment: Seems like a precedence issue. The `.env.local` file is being used instead of the env vars. You need to verify that at the app level.

Comment: Where can I check that ?

Comment: It's already documented in the docs. See https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#environment-variable-load-order. The first one in the sequence is `process.env`. Apparently, you're not using `process.env` and that's why it's going next to look for `.env.local.` file. You need to verify and update your code accordingly.